# Exception Handling in Qt for Class Hierarchy

Tags: c++, qt, exception

I am working on developing a Qt application for windows platform. I am facing problem when using exception handling in class hierarchy.

I have Class B object instantiated in a function of Class A. When, due to some reason, an exception is thrown from Class B (and not caught in Class B) it is not being caught in Class A (appropriate try-catch block is present in Class A) and instead the application crashes showing some windows specific error. This type of try-catch mechanism in class hierarchy works perfectly fine in Java.

Example:

This is piece of code of ClassA that is instatiating an object of ClassB (Qt Dialog)

```
void Class A::on_pbCallB_clicked()
{
    try
    {
        objClassB = new ClassB();
        objClassB->show();
    }
    catch(QString *strExceptionMsg)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error",*strExceptionMsg);
        exit(1);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        QMessageBox::critical(this,"Error","Uknown Error");
        exit(1);
    }
}
```

When ClassB dialog is displayed and a button present on the dialog is pressed following piece of code is called:

```
void ClassB::on_pbThrowExp_clicked()
{
    try
    {
        throw (new QString("Throwing Exception !"));
    }
    catch(QString *strExceptionMsg)
    {
        throw strExceptionMsg;
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        throw (new QString("Unknown Error"));
    }
}
```

This throws an exception which is caught in ClassB's function but when thrown further it is not caught in ClassA (From where objClassB is instantiated) and the entire application crashes.

I have tried 1 solution where I have re-implemented QApplication’s **notify** method where, an exception thrown from somewhere in the application, if not caught anywhere, is being caught in re-implemented notify method. But doing this does not stop the application from closing down.

Please confirm if this is even possible in Qt/C++ and if not please point me in direction of an alternative (if available) in Qt.

Comment: Please provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Hard to tell exactly what's going on with just a description of code.

Comment: http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/ ?

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have added example code and some info abt what I have tried already. Hope this would make the problem more clear.

Comment: You're leaking QStrings - don't create them on the heap. Use `throw QString(...)` and `catch(const QString& ...)`. Other than that: If `on_pbThrowExp_clicked()` was called from A, your code would work. But it isn't, it's called by the event handling code for the button click. Exceptions leaving slots can only be caught in notify(), and are thus not very meaningful - best practice is to make sure all exceptions are caught in slots.

Comment: @Frank ..Thanks for info on leaking QStrings....about exceptions, I guess I don't have any option other than to catch them in the slot.

Answer (score 4):

This is an old question, but since there still might be people trying to combine Qt with exception handling, following is a solution that worked for me. It requires c++11 support though.

application.hpp:

```
#ifndef APPLICATION_HPP
#define APPLICATION_HPP

#include <QApplication>
#include <exception>

///
/// This class catches any exceptions thrown inside proc()
/// and shows them using the message() function.
/// The virtual message() function can be overriden to customize
/// how the messages are shown. The default implementation
/// shows them using QMessageBox.
///
class Application: public QApplication
{
public:
    Application(int& argc, char* argv[]);
    bool notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event);

    virtual int proc() { return exec(); }
    int run();

    virtual int message(const std::string&);

private:
    std::exception_ptr _M_e = nullptr;
};

#endif // APPLICATION_HPP
```

application.cpp

```
#include "application.hpp"
#include <QMessageBox>

Application::Application(int& argc, char* argv[]):
    QApplication(argc, argv)
{ }

int Application::run()
{
    try
    {
        int code = proc();
        // Check if an exception was thrown and stored in Application::notify
        // and if so, rethrow it.
        if(_M_e) std::rethrow_exception(_M_e);

        return code;
    }
    catch(std::exception& e)
    {
        return message(e.what());
    }
}

int Application::message(const std::string& message)
{
    QMessageBox::critical(0, "Error", QString::fromStdString(message));
    return 1;
}

///
/// Qt does not allow exceptions thrown from event handlers
/// to be processed outside the event loop.
/// So we catch them here, store them in _M_e
/// and tell the application to exit.
///
bool Application::notify(QObject* receiver, QEvent* event)
{
    try
    {
        return QApplication::notify(receiver, event);
    }
    catch(...)
    {
        _M_e = std::current_exception();
        exit();
    }
    return false;
}
```

You can use the `Application` class as you would the `QApplication`, except call the `run` function instead of `exec`. (Alternatively, rename `run` into `exec` to hide `QApplication`'s `exec`.)

You can override the `message` function to customize error messages. You can also override the `proc` function to add some initialization/destruction code before/after `exec`.