# Why don't c++ try-catch blocks work with g++ on ubuntu?

Tags: c++, qt, gcc, exception, g++

I made a QT Test Application (an app with a GUI that tests some functions I made) for my work project but my exceptions don't work at all and I don't understand why. Maybe I'm missing something but the code seems correct to me, here's a sample:

The function that throws the exception in (with my test it throws `std::invalid_argument`):

```
std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> cloud_manip::fragment_cloud(
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_ptr, float max_scaled_fragment_depth)
{
    if (!cloud_ptr)
    {
        throw invalid_cloud_pointer();
    }

    if ((aux::cmp_floats(max_scaled_fragment_depth, 0.00, 0.005)) || (max_scaled_fragment_depth < 0))
        throw std::invalid_argument("Invalid max fragment depth.");

    float curr_depth = FLT_MAX;
    std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> cloud_fragments;

    for (unsigned int cloud_it = 0; cloud_it < cloud_ptr->points.size(); cloud_it++)
    {
        // end of a fragment
        if ((cloud_ptr->points[cloud_it].y > (curr_depth + max_scaled_fragment_depth))
                || (cloud_ptr->points[cloud_it].y < (curr_depth - max_scaled_fragment_depth)) )
        {
            curr_depth = cloud_ptr->points[cloud_it].y;
            pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr new_cloud(new pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>);
            cloud_fragments.push_back(new_cloud);
        }

        // filling current cloud
        else
            (cloud_fragments.back())->points.push_back(cloud_ptr->points[cloud_it]);
    }

    return cloud_fragments;
}
```

The first function that catches the exception:

```
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr fast_normal_estimation(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr cloud_ptr, int max_neighbs,
                                                    float radius, float x_scale, float y_scale, float z_scale, float max_fragment_depth)
{
    try
    {
        // the cloud colored by its normal vectors; return value
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr colored_cloud_ptr;

        float max_scaled_fragment_depth = max_fragment_depth / y_scale;

        cloud_manip::scale_cloud(cloud_ptr, x_scale, y_scale, z_scale); // scaling cloud

        std::vector<pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr> cloud_fragments =
                cloud_manip::fragment_cloud(cloud_ptr, max_scaled_fragment_depth); // fragmenting cloud for less execution time

        // estimating the normals for each cloud fragment in parallel
        // #pragma omp parallel for schedule(static)
        for (unsigned int i = 0; i < cloud_fragments.size(); i++)
        {
            normal_estimation(cloud_fragments[i], radius, max_neighbs);
        }

        colored_cloud_ptr = cloud_manip::merge_clouds(cloud_fragments); // merging fragments to build original cloud

        cloud_manip::scale_cloud(colored_cloud_ptr, (1.0/x_scale), (1.0/y_scale), (1.0/z_scale));    // restoring widop scale

        return colored_cloud_ptr;
    }

    catch (const std::logic_error& le)
    {
        throw le;
    }
}
```

The test function:

```
void test_normal_estimation(std::string import_path, std::string export_path, float radius,
                            int max_neighbs, float x_scale, float y_scale, float z_scale,
                            float max_fragment_depth)
{
    try
    {
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr base_cloud;
        pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::Ptr colored_cloud;   // output cloud

        base_cloud = cloud_io::import_cloud(import_path);
        colored_cloud = fast_normal_estimation(base_cloud, max_neighbs, radius, x_scale, y_scale, z_scale,
                                               max_fragment_depth);
        cloud_io::export_cloud(export_path + "normal_estimation_test_" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(radius) + "_"
                                + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(max_neighbs) + "_" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(x_scale) + "_"
                                + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(y_scale) + "_" + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(z_scale) + "_"
                                + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(max_fragment_depth) + ".txt", colored_cloud);
    }

    catch(const std::logic_error& le)
    {
        throw le;
    }
}
```

And lastly the interface which is supposed to show an error message:

```
void normal_estimation_test_form::on_launch_test_btn_clicked()
{
    // for when the test is done
    QMessageBox done;

    this->setEnabled(false);

    _ned->radius = ui->radius_dsb->value();
    _ned->max_neighbs = ui->max_neighbs_sb->value();
    _ned->x_scale = ui->x_scale_dsb->value();
    _ned->y_scale = ui->y_scale_dsb->value();
    _ned->z_scale = ui->z_scale_dsb->value();
    _ned->max_fragment_depth = ui->max_fragm_depth_sb->value();

    try
    {
        test_normal_estimation(_ned->cloud_in_path, _ned->cloud_out_path, _ned->radius,
                               _ned->max_neighbs, _ned->x_scale, _ned->y_scale,
                               _ned->z_scale, _ned->max_fragment_depth);

        done.setText("Cloud normal estimation test completed.");
        done.exec();
    }

    catch (const std::logic_error& le)
    {
        QErrorMessage q_err_msg;
        QString err_msg;

        err_msg.append("Invalid input.");
        q_err_msg.showMessage(err_msg, "Input Error");
    }
}
```

Any idea why my exception doesn't get caught at all? Thank you in advance.

**edit_1:** I know I'm not catching `std::invalid_argument` but that's because it's a sub-class of `std::logic_error` according to [cplusplus](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/stdexcept/invalid_argument/).

Comment: If I catch `std::invalid_argument` after catching `std::logic_error` QT shows me a warning saying that `std::invalid_argument` is a sub-class of `std::logic_error` so it's always caught in the `std::logic_error` block.

Comment: are you sure it's throwing it?

Comment: I've used the debugger to check it step by step and yes, it enter the `if` block. It then throws it and nothing happens. My `normal_estimation_test_form` window gets disabled (as it should when the test is launched) but using htop (task manager for ubuntu) I can see that my normal estimation function is not running (because when it does it uses 1 core at 100%).

Comment: Please post a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). By devising one you will very probably solve your problem.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: I have made a small QT Console App like so:

`try { throw std::logic_error("Logic error test."); } catch (const std::logic_error& le) { std::cout << le.what() << std::endl; }` 

It works, I'm gonna look more into it.

Comment: Remove all your `catch(const std::logic_error& le)  { throw le;  }` code, it's doing nothing useful.

Comment: Ok, so that was another question I wanted to ask. Don't I have to get catch each step of the way or can I just catch it at the end?

Comment: @VladAdrianMoglan - only catch when you can/need do something (recover, report etc).  Use RAII to release any resources.

Comment: Ok so this definitely has something to do with using a graphical interface/a dialog window. I am catching the exception before and executing `std::cout << "CAUGHT!" << std::endl;` and it displays `CAUGHT!` as application output.

Comment: If you are trying to try/catch in response to a message dispatched from the dialog/windows manager, then this will not work as the OS/window-manager stack probably cannot propagate C++ exceptions.  Message handling functions are "callbacks" and you should not let exceptions exit them.

Comment: Could you please detail your comment as an answer below?

Answer (score 0):

I have found an answer to the problem and it is explained here: [exception handling in Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20454542/exception-handling-in-qt-for-class-hierarchy). It doesn't look like a legitimate  way to do it but I don't know of any better.